# Variable scope follow through inside a function in R

Tags: r, scope

Let's say I have defined a function `f1(x)` that calls another function `f2(x)` that someone else owns and I should not touch. I want variables that I define in `f1` to be available in `f2` without passing additional arguments.

Here is and example:

```
a<-4 # A global variable
f2<-function(x,b){
     return(a*b*x) #accesses a global variable and one that I want to define inside f1
}
f1<-function(x){
     b<-2 # Note: I do not want to use b<<-2 because it messes up my .GlobalEnv
     y = f2(x) # This produces error saying 'b' is undefined
     return(y)
}
f1(10) # This should produce 80 (= 4*2*10) but gives error that 'b' is not defined
```

I appreciate any input.

Thanks!

Comment: So, one thing you didn't do with the above function is feed `f2()` an argument for `b`. Since there isn't a default, that won't work. Why couldn't you write, `f1<-function(x){
     b<-2 
     y = f2(x, b) 
     return(y)
}` ?

Comment: Thanks @jacobsg. The reason is very complicated. f2 is written by someone else. I have a lot of b's and  a lot of f2's like this that use variables outside of function. If I do what you suggested, I have to do it across the board and it will be very time consuming. To make thinks more complicated I am not aware of all of b's. Only through trial and error can I find all the b's for one f2.

Answer (score 0):

Hi r uses lexicographical scoping. Shortly explained this means that a function can access all variables that are available in the scope in which the function is defined are also available in the function.

What you want to do is something like this.

```
a<-4 # A global variable

f1<-function(x){
     b<-2 # Note: I do not want to use b<<-2 because it messes up my .GlobalEnv
f2<-function(x){
     return(a*b*x) #accesses a global variable and one that I want to define inside f1
}
     y = f2(x) # This produces error saying 'b' is undefined
     return(y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a deep dive in the www, I found an answer to my question. If you assume that each of functions are written in an .R file, you can call this inside `f1` and it fixes the problem:

```
eval(parse(file = 'path to f2.R'))
```

This essentially redefines `f2` inside `f1`. `source` did not work here.

Thanks all for your suggestions.